# Is there a way for linking R and Mathematica?

Tags: r, wolfram-mathematica, integral

I have a "for" loop in my code in R and I want to calculate an integral in each counter. Unfortunately, R can`t calculate this integral and result is : the integral is probably divergent!! whereas this integral is calculated by Mathematica.
Is there a way to link between R and Mathematica for calculating this integral in each count in the loop and save the result in a vector in R?

Following is my code in R: `alpha1[j]` is a constant.

```
v <- c()
for(j in 1:16){
g8 <- function(y){ alpha1[j]*((log(1-y))^2)*((1-y)^2)*(y^(3*alpha1[j]-3))/((1-(y^alpha1[j]))^2)}
v[j] <- integrate(g8,0,1)$value
}
```

Comment: see [create-a-mathematica-function-that-can-be-called-from-r-or-matlab](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/115090/create-a-mathematica-function-that-can-be-called-from-r-or-matlab)

Comment: Perhaps spend some time studying the material at https://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/ExternalLanguageInterfaces.html